# Help me find a material with low acoustic impedance but high wave velocity

Tags: acoustics, electrical-resistance, material-science

I'm trying to find a material that would have two seemingly opposite qualities. I need something with low acoustic impedance, like a plastic, but also with high wave velocity (more precisely shear wave velocity above 2500 m/s) like a metal.
Is there material you know of that would be a good in between? Glassy carbon is a good candidate for example.
Thanks a lot.

Edit:
Thanks for your suggestions, I will be more explicit on my constraints. The material needs to have:

- shear wave velocity > 2500 m/s
- acoustic impedance < 8 MRayl

I don't know if such material exists or if it is possible. Maybe someone here knows.

Comment: Maybe you could find your answer here: https://engineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Could it be that you mix up electrical resistance with acoustic impedance?

Answer (score 1):

Low acoustic impedance comes from a low product of density and stiffness. High wave velocity comes from a high ratio of stiffness to density. So, your requirements favor low density but conflict on stiffness. That suggests looking for an extremely low density material with moderate stiffness. Perhaps aerogel?

Comment: Thank you for the breakdown. Aerogel doesn't have a high enough wave velocity unfortunately. I think the ideal candidate would be a very stiff plastic.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to maximize the ratio between wave velocity and acoustic impedance. Let say we call it "p". But this is just the inverse of density. The stiffness is irrelevant. However, if your velocity needs to be larger than some threshold, for a given (acceptable) ratio p, you can find the minimum stiffness and maximum density. Beryllium have pretty high shear modulus for relatively low density. What is the minimum ratio (p) that will be OK?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, unfortunately beryllium impedance is too high. I updated my question to be more precise.